# Ruby/Watir - Clicking inside of a text box

Tags: html, ruby, textbox, watir

How do you use Watir to manually click inside of a text box?  This is so that I can send keys using the `send_keys` method instead of using the `text_field.set` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send keys to a specific element (eg text field), you should not need to click it first. The Watir API allows you to send keys to a specific element. For example:

```
text_field(:id => 'my_id').send_keys('a')
```

However, if you need to click the element to initiate some javascript, then try:

```
text_field(:id => 'my_id').click
text_field(:id => 'my_id').send_keys('a')
```

Comment: one request to you.. could you give me the API doc link for watir-web-driver,you used in your daily life programming..

Comment: @Babai, The watir-webdriver API docs can be found at http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/frames

Comment: That I am aware of.Couple of weeks back,I found one nice API doc for this,but forgot to bookmark the same.So I thought I should ask you,if you by luck use that link.. But at last no luck.... :(( still thanks for your reply...

Comment: @Babai, Maybe you were looking at watirwebdriver.com or the watirbook (https://leanpub.com/watirbook)?